# Using genfromtxt to import csv data with missing values in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I have a csv file that looks something like this (actual file has many more columns and rows):

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
16
```

Say the name of the file is **info.csv**
If I try to import this using

```
data = numpy.genfromtxt('info.csv', delimiter = ',')
```

then I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Some errors were detected ! Line #4 (got 1 columns instead of 5)
```

If I use,

```
data = numpy.genfromtxt('info.csv', delimiter = ',', skip_footer = 1)
```

both lines with data `16` and with data `11, 12, 13, 14, 15` are skipped. I don't understand why the line with `11, 12, 13, 14, 15` is being skipped. I would appreciate any help on how I can appropriately use the `genfromtxt` to import first three lines in the above file.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you can ignore the 16 at the end of the file try using the

`invalid_raise` (**bool, optional**) parameter
if set to False it ignores all incomplete lines without throwing an exception

see here (its the last parameter before the examples)
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Comment: Thanks! This works well for me. But can you or someone explain why skip_footer is not working. Or, how can I get the row with 16 in it. I will accept the answer later, because if I do so now, those questions will remain unanswered. Thanks again.

Comment: it skips 2 rows, becaus genformtxt reads the valid rows into an array and then skips as mamy as you told him, but the line with '16' is never read into the array

Comment: you can try the 'filling_values' or 'missing_values' parameter to fill the missing 4 values in the line with '16', for example by -1 and or 0 depending on what you do with your array after reading it from disk

Comment: can you please explain how to use filling_values. I tried, `numpy.genfromtxt('info.csv', delimiter = ',', filling_values = 0)`. However, that still gives the same error.

Comment: ok - i checked the code of numpy now, filling_values can be used to fill in empty values - so if your last line looks like '16,,,," fill would fill the empty values. if the line has no delimiters genfromtxt can't parse it

Answer (score 0):

The command `filling_values` also helped me. I set it to zero. Thus each empty value is set to zero. It probably doesn't always make sense, but maybe it will help you.