# genfromtxt in python code for missing columns

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7, statsmodels

Input csv file:

```
a,b,c,d,e
1,2,3,4,2
3,4,5,6,3
3,4,5
1,2
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt("sa.csv", dtype=None, delimiter=',', names=True)
print data['a'],data['b'],data['e']
```

I ll get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cs.py", line 3, in <module>
    data = np.genfromtxt("sa.csv", dtype=None, delimiter=',', names=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1593, in genfromtxt
    raise ValueError(errmsg)
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #4 (got 3 columns instead of 5)
    Line #5 (got 2 columns instead of 5)
```

How to deal with this and perform correlation based on the selected columns using statsmodels in python??

Comment: I've tidied up your post a little bit - although your traceback is still a bit wonky - you may wish to copy/paste and put in the trackback again. This time, paste it in, highlight the lot and press ctrl+k on it... Or the little `{}` icon when you click on [edit]

Comment: sorry i waz new to this i would learn it

Comment: to calculate correlation, you can just use ``np.corrcoef``, or ``np.ma.corrcoef`` if you have missing values, or use pandas. statsmodels doesn't duplicate and doesn't have those functions.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention `statsmodels` I assume that you've got its `pandas` dependency installed. Pandas will parse your example properly:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dat = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
np.corrcoef(dat)

array([[ 1.        ,  0.94174191,         nan,         nan],
       [ 0.94174191,  1.        ,         nan,         nan],
       [        nan,         nan,         nan,         nan],
       [        nan,         nan,         nan,         nan]])
```

Which is correct given the missing values.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it ignore the lines with fewer columns ([Using genfromtxt to import csv data with missing values in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761103/using-genfromtxt-to-import-csv-data-with-missing-values-in-numpy)), but you cannot make it parse them as incomplete.  If you put the delimiters in place (i.e. `1,2,,,`) it can work, but otherwise I don't think `genfromtxt` is smart enough to do what you want.

You could easily implement it yourself, though, using the `csv` module.

Comment: It takes a negative value -1

Comment: How to perform correlation for the two columns

Comment: That sounds like a second, unrelated question.  I suggest you post it separately.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had special character # inside my data what caused the problem.
Example:

```
a,b#,c,d,e
1,2,3,4,2
```

Solution:

change the comments character, I changed it to: @@@

```
dataset = genfromtxt(open(file,'r'), delimiter=',', dtype='f8',
comments='@@@@')[1:]
```