# Excluding certain rows while importing data with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, file-import

I am generating data-sets from experiments. I end up with csv data-sets that are typically are `n x 4` dimensional (`n` rows; `n > 1000` and `4` columns). However, due to an artifact of the data-collection process, typically the first couple of rows and the last couple of rows have only 2 or 3 columns. So a data-set looks like:

```
8,0,4091
8,0,
8,0,4091,14454
10,0,4099,14454
2,0,4094,14454
8,-3,4104,14455
3,0,4100,14455
....
....
14,-1,4094,14723
0,3,4105,14723
7,0,4123,14723
7,
6,-2,4096,
3,2,
```

As you can see, the first two rows and the last three don't have the 4 columns that I expect. When I try importing this file using `np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter = ',')`, I get an error. Once I remove the rows which have fewer than 4 columns (first 2 rows, and last 3 rows, in this case), the import works fine.

Two questions:

1. Why doesn't the usual importing work. I am not sure what is the exact error in this importing. In other words, why is not having the same number of columns in all rows a problem?
2. As a workaround, I know how to ignore the first two rows while importing the files with numpy `np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows= 2)`, but is there a simple way to also select a fixed number of rows at the bottom to ignore?

Note: This is NOT about finding unique rows in a numpy array. Its more about importing csv data that are non-uniform in the number of columns that each row contains.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find unique rows in numpy.array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array)

Comment: @JosephFarah This is not about finding unique rows in numpy array. This is about importing csv files with non-uniform structure (rows, columns). I can't even create the numpy array at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is similar (duplicate) to [Using genfromtxt to import csv data with missing values in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761103/using-genfromtxt-to-import-csv-data-with-missing-values-in-numpy)

1) I'm not sure about why this is the default behavior.

- Could be to warn users that the CSV file might be corrupt.
- Could be to optimize the array and make it *N x M*, instead of having multiple column lengths.

2) Use numpy's genfromtext. For this you'll need to know the correct number of columns in advance.

```
data = numpy.genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',', usecols=[0,1,2,3], invalid_raise=False)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This still gives me an error:                                                               `ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #3 (got 4 columns instead of 3)
    Line #4 (got 4 columns instead of 3)......` Approach above works.

Comment: Try it now, I forgot to set invalid_raise to False!

Comment: Nope still doesn't work @rafaelvalle. Still get `ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #3 (got 4 columns instead of 3)
    Line #4 (got 4 columns instead of 3).....` Interestingly at the very end I get :`[[    8.     0.  4091.]
 [    8.     0.    nan]
 [    8.     0.  4091.]
 [    8.     0.    nan]]
(4, 3)`

Comment: Please try it again adding the usecols argument. It is a list with the indices of the valid columns. In your example, [0,1,2,3]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `genfromtxt`, which allows to skip lines a the beginning **and** at the end:

```
np.genfromtxt('array.txt', delimiter=',', skip_header=2, skip_footer=3)
```